# Orbits of action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on matrices of fixed determinant

Tags: matrices, number-theory

The following question is an exercise from a [lecture series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsnLgx1a65o) on modular forms by M Ram Murty. Let $X_m$ be the set of matrices of determinant $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on $X_m$ (say, on the left) by matrix multiplication. The exercise is to show that the number of orbits is finite and that the orbit representatives are given by
\begin{equation}T=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix}:d>0,ad=m, b\mod d
\right\}.
\end{equation}
I can show that these representatives are in disjoint orbits. But I'm not sure how to show that they are a complete set, i.e. I want to show that for any $M\in X_m$, there are matrices $A\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $B\in T$ such that $AB=M$.

Comment: What does "$b\mod d$" mean in the specification of $T$?

Comment: Apparently this means that $0\leq b<d$.

Comment: Hint: Perform the Euclidean algorithm for gcd using elementary rows operations on the first column of a given matrix.

Comment: @user1551 Apologies, I should have stated that $m$ is a natural number. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
X=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & u \\
  y & v
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $x,y,u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\det(X)=m$.

1. If $\gcd(x,y)=t$ and $x=tx'$, $y=ty'$, then $\gcd(x',y')=1$ and
   let's choose a matrix $A$ of the form

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x'' & y'' \\
  y' & -x'
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Prove that the $x'',y''$ can be replaced
by integers so that $A\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

2. Check that

$$
X_1=AX=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & d
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $a,b,d\in\mathbb{Z}$, $ad=m$.

3. If $d<0$, then multiply $X_1$ by the matrix $-I$,
   where $I$ is a unit matrix. Consider further that $d>0$.
4. Let $b=dq+r$, where $0\leq r<d$.
   Multiply $X_1$ by the matrix

$$
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & q \\
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Check that the matrix $BX_1$ has the form we want.

5. It remains to prove that any two different matrices $X,Y$ of the specified kind lie in different orbits.